# Pass value from button to the method in Dialog - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog

I have a dialog in React which displays some information and has 2 buttons Proceed and Cancel. 
If the `Cancel` button is clicked the Dialog closes ( working fine) 
But if the `Proceed` button is clicked I want to send the flag to the original method from where this dialog open command was sent to proceed and complete the action.

```
<Dialog {...reProps} ref={(x) => { this.restriced = x; }}>
 <div>
   SOME INFORMATION
   </div>
   <div>Do you want to apply profile to the rest of the devices.</div>
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleCancel}>
        Cancel
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.handleProceed}>
        Yes
        </button>
    </div>
</Dialog>
```

```
onProfileApply(profileName, restrict) {
    if (!_.isEmpty(devices)) {
        _.forEach(devices, (device) => {
            if (restrictedDevices.length !== 0) {
                return this.setState({
                    restrictedDevices
                }, () => {
                    this.restriced.open();
                });
            }
        }
            const APIBody = {
            'devices': selectedDevices
        };

        return this.props.dispatch(actions.updateDevices(APIBody));
    }
    return null;
}

 handleCancel() {
    this.restriced.close();
}

handleProceed() {

}
```

I want this action to be executed when the user clicks Proceed button but the information is not available outside the onProfileApply function.

```
return this.props.dispatch(actions.updateDevices(APIBody));
```

Is there any chance I can go back to the function and execute this if the flag is true or something. Please help.

Comment: Your question is not clear: "method from where this dialog open command was sent to proceed", build [a minimal sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) it will help.

Comment: It's slightly difficult to see where all of this is happening, but it looks like you could just set the components `state` to the `selectedDevices` and then use them in `handleProceed()`.

Comment: I want to send the information from the dialog to the parent which is onProfileApply. Tried the onClosed().subscribe too but it doesnt work